# Flutter plugin: Send data from Android BroadcastReceiver to Flutter code

Tags: android, flutter, broadcastreceiver, flutter-plugin

I'm developing a Flutter plugin (for Android only) that automatically executes a Flutter task when the device connects to a specific bluetooth device.

Here is what I do in the **Android** side of the plugin:

1. In the manifest, I register a `BroadcastReceiver` that listen to bluetooth events.

```
<receiver android:name=".BluetoothBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2. In my 'FlutterPlugin' class, I initialise an `EventChannel` and set a `StreamHandler`. Then, I keep a reference of the `EventSink` that is provided in the `onListen` function of the `StreamHandler`. This allows me to send data from the Android side of the plugin to the Flutter side of the plugin.

```
class BluetoothPlugin : FlutterPlugin {

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        EventChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "event_channel_bluetooth_event")
            .setStreamHandler(object : StreamHandler {

                override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink) {
                    BluetoothPlugin.eventSink = eventSink
                }

                override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {}

        })
    }

    companion object {
        var eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null
    }

}
```

3. Inside the `onReceive` function of my `BroadCastReceiver`, I use the `EventSink` to notify the Flutter side of the plugin that a bluetooth event happened.

```
class BluetoothReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) {
            BluetoothPlugin.eventSink?.success("Bluetooth device is connected")
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what I do in the **Flutter** side of the plugin:

1. I setup an `EventChannel` that will listen to any message that is passed to the `EventSink`.

```
EventChannel('event_channel_bluetooth_event').receiveBroadcastStream().listen(
  (data) {
    // A bluetooth event happened
  },
);
```

Everything works perfectly when the app is running (in the foreground and in the background).
However, if the app is killed, the `BluetoothBroadcastReceiver` (in the Android side of the plugin) can't pass any data to the Flutter side of the plugin because the `EventChannel` is not initialised.

I could not find any way to "wake up" the Flutter side of the plugin (and thus initialise the `EventChannel`) when the `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you managed _to "wake up" the Flutter side of the plugin_? Have you resolved the problem of calling Dart/Flutter code from BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a very interesting post on Medium that explains how to send data from native (Android) code to Dart after the app was terminated: https://medium.com/@chetan882777/initiating-calls-to-dart-from-the-native-side-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugin-7d46aed32c47