# How to start Flutter processing from Android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: flutter, broadcastreceiver, background-process

## Requirement

I would like to implement a Flutter app, which is:

1. Triggered by a broadcast action `ACL_CONNECTED` on Android and then it
2. Processes information about the connected device in Dart (Flutter) and based on the result it
3. Starts a foreground service with a notification, which continues processing and can open the UI if tapped on the notification

## Idea

1. Add `application/receiver` tag to `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Implement `BroadcastReceiver/onReceive`, which gives over processing to Dart/Flutter
3. Continue processing in Dart

*Note: using static BroadcastReveiver will allow to skip starting the app and keeping it running in background.*

## Challenge

It is not clear how to give the processing from Android to Dart/Flutter. If the app is working it is possible using [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels): `MethodChannel.invokeMethod` from Android side and catch it by `MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler` from Flutter side.

In case of static [BroadcastReviever](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) no other part of Android or Flutter code is initialized, so it looks like `MethodChannel.invokeMethod` is ending up in the void.

## Question

How to start Flutter processing from Android BroadcastReceiver?

## Similar questions

Which unfortunately are left without clear answer:

- [Flutter plugin: Send data from Android BroadcastReceiver to Flutter code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164094/flutter-plugin-send-data-from-android-broadcastreceiver-to-flutter-code)
- [How to stream data from Broadcast Receiver to Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008136/how-to-stream-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-flutter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232241/10475643

## Possible alternative solutions

- **Dynamic BroadcastReceiver**
  Maybe the app can be started after Android starts and register `BroadcastReviever` dynamically and the callback in Dart will be initialized, but also we should be sure, that the app is not killed by the system.
- **Start the main Flutter app from static BroadcastReceiver**
  Special parameter can be transferred. If this special parameter is received on app start - use alternative logic - make the required processing and minimize or close the app without even displaying the UI to avoid user distraction.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We are having a very similar problem at the moment: as long as the Flutter/Dart Engine is running, data can easily be exchanged. But we didn't yet figure out how to "wake up" Flutter/Dart

Comment: @GeroldBusch I ended up implementing the whole action, supposed to be triggered from the BroadcastReceiver, in native Android. So UI is in Flutter now and the business logic for background actions in native.